# Need bootstrap modal popup to appear at the center of the screen and should not be able to scroll the screen at the back

Tags: css, popup, modal-dialog

So I have this modal in my code:

```
<div class="modal" id="equityTransactions">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                <div class="modal-title">Item Drill Down</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:50%">ITEM NAME</td>
                            <td style="width:50%">AMOUNT</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Item A</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TableSix.Total_Equity_Domestic)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Item B</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TableSix.Total_Equity_EuroArea)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is exactly what is mentioned in the title. :)

Currently the modal pops up at the top of the page and also I can use scroll on the page at the back of the modal while the pop up is still active. I want to be able to NOT scroll and get the modal to be positioned at the center of the screen.

I am using the default bootstrap css without any changes in it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please show us some working example where we can see problem. With just your `HTML` code, we are not able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
$('body').css('position','fixed');
```

Do you use the latest version? you can see- [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7501)